# Set axis for multiple plots in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gif

I'm working on a population pyramide that should be saved as a gif. [Kind of like in this tutorial of Flowing Data](http://flowingdata.com/2015/11/03/animated-pyramid-chart-in-r/), but with `ggplot` instead of `plotrix`.

My workflow:

1) Create a population pyramide

2) Create multiple pyramide-plots in a `for`-loop

```
for (i in unique(d$jahr)) {

  d_jahr <- d %>%
    filter(jahr == i)

  p <- ggplot(data = d_jahr, aes(x = anzahl, y = value, fill = art)) +
    geom_bar(data = filter(d_jahr, art == "w"), stat = "identity") +
    geom_bar(data = filter(d_jahr, art == "m"), stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = paste(i), x = NULL, y = NULL)

  ggsave(p,filename=paste("img/",i,".png",sep=""))

}
```

3) Save the plots as gif with the `animation` package

My problem:

All years have different values, so the x-axis have different ranges. This results in weird looks in a gif, because the center of the plots jumps to the right, to the left, to the right...

Is it possible to fix the x-axis (in this case y-axis, because of `coord-flip()`) over multiple plots that are created independently?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Maybe this package: https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [proding a minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) and edit your post accordingly. I.e., provide input data (dummy or real) and reduce the code to the lines that are part of the problem (e.g. prob is ggplot, not saving a jpeg).

Comment: @zx8754 gganimate seems like a good idea, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can fix the range of an axis by setting the `limits` parameter:

```
library(ggplot2)
lst <- list(
  data.frame(x = 1:100, y=runif(100, 0, 10)),
  data.frame(x = 1:100, y=runif(100, 0, 100))
)
ylim <- range(do.call(c, lapply(lst, "[[", "y")))
for (x in seq(lst)) {
  print(ggplot(lst[[x]], aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(limits=ylim))
}
```

or by adding `+ylim(ylim)` instead of `+scale_y_continuous(limits=ylim)` (via @DeveauP).

Comment: If it is to set limits, `xlim`or `ylim` functions may more appropriate than `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: Right, added that. Thx!